# yii 2.0 findOne returning same data but twice

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

I am using yii 2.0 with xampp and trying to run this query

```
$model = Students::find()->where('student_id = '.$id.'')->one();
```

and `student_id` is primary key and as expected this query should return only one data, which is returning, but the same data is being returned twice.
The output of the query is as follows

```
`object(app\models\Students)#72 (8) {
  ["_attributes":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=>
  array(12) {
    ["student_id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["student_name"]=>
    string(10) "Anil Kumar"
    ["student_parent_id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["student_class"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["student_section"]=>
    string(1) "A"
    ["st_admsn_date"]=>
    string(10) "2017-07-01"
    ["student_image_url"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["st_perm_address"]=>
    string(29) "31 APC Road, Kolkata - 700023"
    ["st_present_address"]=>
    string(29) "31 APC Road, Kolkata - 700023"
    ["st_blood_group"]=>
    string(2) "B+"
    ["st_medical_history"]=>
    string(2) "OK"
    ["school_id"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  ["_oldAttributes":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=>
  array(12) {
    ["student_id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["student_name"]=>
    string(10) "Anil Kumar"
    ["student_parent_id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["student_class"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["student_section"]=>
    string(1) "A"
    ["st_admsn_date"]=>
    string(10) "2017-07-01"
    ["student_image_url"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["st_perm_address"]=>
    string(29) "31 APC Road, Kolkata - 700023"
    ["st_present_address"]=>
    string(29) "31 APC Road, Kolkata - 700023"
    ["st_blood_group"]=>
    string(2) "B+"
    ["st_medical_history"]=>
    string(2) "OK"
    ["school_id"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  ["_related":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["_errors":"yii\base\Model":private]=>
  NULL
  ["_validators":"yii\base\Model":private]=>
  NULL
  ["_scenario":"yii\base\Model":private]=>
  string(7) "default"
  ["_events":"yii\base\Component":private]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["_behaviors":"yii\base\Component":private]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}`
```

This is my model

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;

class Students extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{

    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'students';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['student_name', 'student_parent_id', 'student_class', 'student_section', 'st_admsn_date', 'student_image_url', 'st_perm_address', 'st_present_address', 'st_blood_group', 'st_medical_history'], 'required'],
            [['student_parent_id', 'school_id'], 'integer'],
            [['st_admsn_date'], 'safe'],
            [['student_name'], 'string', 'max' => 200],
            [['student_class'], 'string', 'max' => 100],
            [['student_section', 'st_blood_group'], 'string', 'max' => 50],
            [['student_image_url'], 'string', 'max' => 400],
            [['st_perm_address', 'st_present_address', 'st_medical_history'], 'string', 'max' => 300],
        ];
    }


    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'student_id' => 'Student ID',
            'student_name' => 'Student Name',
            'student_parent_id' => 'Student Parent ID',
            'student_class' => 'Student Class',
            'student_section' => 'Student Section',
            'st_admsn_date' => 'St Admsn Date',
            'student_image_url' => 'Student Image Url',
            'st_perm_address' => 'St Perm Address',
            'st_present_address' => 'St Present Address',
            'st_blood_group' => 'St Blood Group',
            'st_medical_history' => 'St Medical History',
            'school_id' => 'School ID',
        ];
    }
}
```

I want to remove all the `_oldAttributes` data from result. 
Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: If your refer to _attributes and _oldttributes this is normal  .. otherwise  explain better where are the two results

Comment: I didn't get you, BTW i have mentioned the result of the query after *The output of the query is as follows* line of my question

Comment: @TausifAnwar scaisEdge is right - this is typical Yii 2 model output and this is the single model.

Comment: Yes now i got this, that it's an _oldAttribute data, But is there any way that i can unset or remove this data from the result?

Comment: `_oldAttribute` is a very useful feature of `ActiveRecord`. You may `$model = Students::find()->where('student_id = '.$id.'')->asArray->one();` to get rid of it.

Comment: or call `$model->getAttributes()`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem after using following line on `$model`

```
$result = $model->getAttributes();
```

It gives me the data in array.
If you want to use the object you should not be bothering about the oldAttributes.
It does not intervene, in the operations involved with single object.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to improve your query as :

```
$model=Student::findOne([$id]);
echo "<pre>";print_r($model);echo "</pre>";die;
```

You can direct pass primary key to findOne function.